# right benchmark for an incompletely diversified international portfolio (for a CAPM): MSCI World or MSCI ACWI IMI?

Tags: returns, beta, coherent-risk-measure, capm, currency

I want to calculate annual excess returns on portfolios using monthly returns for a CAPM (for the assets in the portfolio as well as for the benchmark), in order to have more information on the correlations, more precise betas.

I want to use the right benchmark for all this.

Many holdings are diversified internationally,
    but not completely, esp. not into emerging markets (over 1999-2007). Is it appealing to use an MSCI all-world
    benchmark (viz. MSCI ACWI IMI GR USD converted into SEK) as people
    "should" have diversified, so all extra risk is, well, extra? Or it makes
    much more sense to compare everything to an MSCI World (
    developed markets only) benchmark?

Full disclosure: This breaks down my longer question into specifics. Please bear with me. From: [annual excess returns from CAPM on monthly total returns](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/8443/annual-excess-returns-from-capm-on-monthly-total-returns)

Answer (score 1):

Did the portfolio manager have the option of investing in emerging markets?  If yes, use MSCI All-World.  If the portfolio has holdings based in countries with "developed markets" yet has has emerging markets exposure to revenue/earnings, the convention is to use MSCI World.